# Not able to set SalesItemLineDetail tax code in Intuit quickbooks api C#

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add Tax Code for SalesItemLineDetail inside Invoice of Quickbooks online api, but it is not setting tax code correctly when checking it in Online Quickbooks.

Here is my C# Code, which I am using to create Line Item

```
                            Line = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line();
                            InvoiceLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.SalesItemLineDetail();


                            InvoiceLine.ItemRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType
                            {
                                Value = GetItem.Id, // this is inventory Item Id
                                name = GetItem.Name // inventory item name
                            };





                            Line.DetailTypeSpecified = true;
                            Line.DetailType = Intuit.Ipp.Data.LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail;
                            Line.Description = inv.Description;

                            Line.Amount = (inv.Price == null || inv.Price == 0.0) ? (decimal)0.00 : (decimal)inv.Price;
                            Line.AmountSpecified = true;



                            InvoiceLine.Qty = decimal.Parse(inv.Quantity.Value.ToString());
                            InvoiceLine.QtySpecified = true;

                            InvoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject = (inv.Price == null || inv.Price == 0.0) ? (decimal)0.00 : (decimal)(Math.Round(inv.Price.Value, 2) / inv.Quantity.Value);
                            InvoiceLine.ItemElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice;




                            // this line is not settings tax code properly
                            InvoiceLine.TaxCodeRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType
                            {
                                name = taxName,
                                Value = TaxId

                            };


                            //Line Sales Item Line Detail - ServiceDate 
                            InvoiceLine.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
                            InvoiceLine.ServiceDateSpecified = true;

                            //Assign Sales Item Line Detail to Line Item

                            Line.AnyIntuitObject = InvoiceLine;


                            lines.Add(Line);

                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice invoice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice();

                   // SalesOrder is a database table object, and OrderNumber is auto generated number

                    invoice.DocNumber = SalesOrder.OrderNumber.ToString();

                    //TxnDate
                    invoice.TxnDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
                    invoice.TxnDateSpecified = true;


                    invoice.CustomerRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType
                    {
                        Value =  CompanyId
                    };

                    //convert list to array for Intuit Line
                    invoice.Line = lines.ToArray();

                    //TxnTaxDetail
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line taxLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line();
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.TxnTaxDetail txnTaxDetail = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.TxnTaxDetail();
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxLineDetail taxLineDetail = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxLineDetail(); ;
                    //txnTaxDetail.TotalTaxSpecified = true;
                    //txnTaxDetail.TotalTax = decimal.Parse("2");
                    var MainTaxValue = "";
                    txnTaxDetail.TxnTaxCodeRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType()
                    {

                        Value = TaxId,
                        name = SalesOrder.TaxCode.TaxCodeName
                    };
                    foreach (var TAXName in TaxObject.TaxRateDetail)
                    {
                        if(TAXName.TaxRateRef.name.Contains(SalesOrder.TaxCode.TaxCodeName))
                        {
                            MainTaxValue = TAXName.TaxRateRef.value;
                        }
                    }
                    taxLineDetail.TaxRateRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType
                    {
                        Value = MainTaxValue

                    };
                    taxLine.AnyIntuitObject = taxLineDetail;
                    txnTaxDetail.TaxLine = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line[] { taxLine };


                    //DueDate
                    invoice.DueDate = SalesOrder.InvoiceDueDate != null ? SalesOrder.InvoiceDueDate.Value : DateTime.Now.AddDays(30).Date;
                    invoice.DueDateSpecified = true;

                    invoice.TxnTaxDetail = txnTaxDetail;
```

I have tried these reference links, but it is not working for me

https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6500373

[How to export Line items with Tax Code and Value in QBO Canada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171658/how-to-export-line-items-with-tax-code-and-value-in-qbo-canada)

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-non-us-locales

Using above links, I can see we can create Tax Code ref using this line of code, for Each Invoice Line item, but it is not setting value correctly.

```
                           InvoiceLine.TaxCodeRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType
                            {
                                name = taxName,
                                Value = TaxId

                            };
```

But it is not working.
Note: this is non-US company, so I have to specify tax code ref for each Invoice Line.

Edit 1:
Attaching Image of Postman API request, which I sent to Quickbooks for creating invoice.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try by removing the name field  I think it might not be required

```
InvoiceLine.TaxCodeRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType()
                        {

                            Value = TaxId

                        };
```

Comment: yes, already tried it, required field is "value", but it doesn't work and doesn't select correct tax value.

Comment: How are you getting the TaxId value? It should query the `SELECT * from TaxCode where Name ='TaxName';` is this how ur are querying?

Comment: yes, you are right getting TaxId in same way, still same issue.

Comment: Hmm, I generally use their API Explorer to debug the request https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account try that once

Comment: I tried to create invoice using this link https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/invoice#create-an-invoice and postman but wasn't able to set tax code for line item properly using it also

Comment: Is it possible to paste in the xml/json request body you are sending to the api here?

Comment: I have attached an image, take a look, will clear more details.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between our versions is that I let QB calculate the tax.
I commented out the Tax detail line, and told QB that tax amount wasn't included.

```
            //    //TxnTaxDetail
            //    TxnTaxDetail txnTaxDetail = new TxnTaxDetail();
            //    Line taxLine = new Line();
            //    taxLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.TaxLineDetail;
            //    TaxLineDetail taxLineDetail = new TaxLineDetail();
            //    taxLineDetail.TaxRateRef = stateTaxCode.SalesTaxRateList.TaxRateDetail[0].TaxRateRef;
            //    txnTaxDetail.TxnTaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType
            //    {
            //        name = stateTaxCode.Name,
            //        Value = stateTaxCode.Id
            //    };
            //    if (customer.DefaultTaxCodeRef != null)
            //    {
            //        txnTaxDetail.TxnTaxCodeRef = customer.DefaultTaxCodeRef;
            //        taxLineDetail.TaxRateRef = customer.DefaultTaxCodeRef;
            //    }

            //    //Assigning the first Tax Rate in this Tax Code

            //    taxLine.AnyIntuitObject = taxLineDetail;
            //    txnTaxDetail.TaxLine = new[] { taxLine };
            //    invoice.TxnTaxDetail = txnTaxDetail;


            invoice.GlobalTaxCalculationSpecified = true;
            invoice.GlobalTaxCalculation = GlobalTaxCalculationEnum.TaxExcluded;
```

Here is my code for doing this, and it definitely works. I can't see a difference between the two though.This calculates VAT in Europe and puts in the Tax Code.
Hope this helps.

```
            var invlines = new List<Line>();
            foreach (var lineitem in inv.Lines)
            {
                //Line
                Line invoiceLine = new Line();
                //Line Description
                invoiceLine.Description = (((lineitem.PublicationName == "N/A" || lineitem.PublicationName == "-") ? "" : lineitem.PublicationName) + " " + lineitem.Description).Trim();

                //Line Detail Type
                invoiceLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail;
                invoiceLine.DetailTypeSpecified = true;
                //Line Sales Item Line Detail
                SalesItemLineDetail lineSalesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();
                //Line Sales Item Line Detail - ItemRef
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineitem.ItemCode))
                {
                    lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = new ReferenceType()
                    {
                        Value = lineitem.ItemCode
                    };
                }
                else if (item != null)
                {
                    lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = new ReferenceType
                    {
                        name = item.Name,
                        Value = item.Id
                    };
                }

                //Line Sales Item Line Detail - UnitPrice

                //Line Sales Item Line Detail - Qty
                lineSalesItemLineDetail.Qty = 1;
                lineSalesItemLineDetail.QtySpecified = true;
                if (inv.DiscountPercent > 0)
                {
                    invoiceLine.Amount = (decimal)lineitem.PriceBeforeDiscount;
                    invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
                    lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice;
                }
                else
                {
                    invoiceLine.Amount = (decimal)lineitem.Price;
                    invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
                    lineSalesItemLineDetail.AnyIntuitObject = lineitem.Price;
                    lineSalesItemLineDetail.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice;
                }
                //Line Sales Item Line Detail - TaxCodeRef
                //For US companies, this can be 'TAX' or 'NON'
                var taxref = lineitem.TaxAmount == null || lineitem.TaxAmount == 0 ? nonvatid.ToString() : vatid.ToString();
                if (country == "US")
                {
                    taxref = lineitem.TaxAmount == null || lineitem.TaxAmount == 0 ? "NON" : "TAX";
                }
                lineSalesItemLineDetail.TaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType
                {
                    Value = taxref
                };

                //Line Sales Item Line Detail - ServiceDate 
                lineSalesItemLineDetail.ServiceDate = DateTimeService.Now.Date;
                lineSalesItemLineDetail.ServiceDateSpecified = true;
                //Assign Sales Item Line Detail to Line Item
                invoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject = lineSalesItemLineDetail;
                //Assign Line Item to Invoice
                invlines.Add(invoiceLine);
            }
            if (inv.DiscountPercent > 0)
            {
                Line invoiceLine = new Line();
                DiscountLineDetail discLine = new DiscountLineDetail();
                discLine.PercentBased = true;
                discLine.DiscountPercent = (decimal)inv.DiscountPercent;
                discLine.DiscountPercentSpecified = true;
                discLine.PercentBased = true;
                discLine.PercentBasedSpecified = true;
                invoiceLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.DiscountLineDetail;
                invoiceLine.DetailTypeSpecified = true;
                invoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject = discLine;
                invlines.Add(invoiceLine);
                invoice.DiscountRate = (decimal) (inv.DiscountPercent);
                invoice.DiscountRateSpecified = true;
            }
            invoice.Line = invlines.ToArray();
```

Comment: can you add your complete code for creating invoice, with qb api service and getting tax code etc., as I am not able to understand where is my code wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I found solution, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to find the correct solution.

**My Above code is right, there is no issue in it and @sheavens code is also right**.

Actual **problem** was, **I was assigning "default Tax code" to a selected company**, which we cannot override while passing tax code reference in Invoice Line item.

To Check if there is any default code for company, navigate to Companies list in quickbooks online website , Select your desired Company from the list, click "Edit", then in the "Tax Info" tab, uncheck "Assign Default tax code" to pass tax code using Invoice Line item.

Hope this helps other developers, with same problem.